# Prevent a server side script from dumping password

Tags: php, security

I would like to know how do web forms get processed .
Lets say i have a server side script that handles a form submit

```
   echo "Your name: {$_POST['Name']}<br />";
   echo "Your password: {$_POST['Password']}<br />";
```

I don't want a server side programmer (like in the php scrip above) to know or dump the users password to file using some clever tricks.

How do people handle this in form processing ?
I have taken a php example above but this could be any server side language.

Comment: You can hash user password on clint side using javascript before form submit,but remember there may cases when JS is turned off.

Comment: Usually you trust the server side, if you can't then you need to look into alternatives where the user doesn't send his user id / password to your server, at least not in plain text. If you don't trust user credentials to be on your server you should probably outsource the authentication to oauth / social logins.

Comment: Hi JimL You are correct and your advise seems to be sane can you please make your comment as an answer as i cannot think of a better way then doing the way you suggest

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I wrote a small blog post about this: [Preventing users from sending their passwords to others.](http://station.clancats.com/preventing-users-from-sending-there-passwords-to-others/)

---

I developed once a messaging server for a client where i had to prevent that the users where able to send each other their passwords.

( In this example i use `MD5` but i recommend `BCrypt` )

What I did is pretty dead simple:

**1. Save the length of the original password and the hash.**

Password: foobar

```
+--+-----------------+----------------------------------+
|ID| password_length | password                         |
+--+-----------------+----------------------------------+
|01| 6               | 3858f62230ac3c915f300c664312c63f |
+--+-----------------+----------------------------------+
```

**2. When saving a new message we have to check each word.**

```
function saveNewMessage( Messenger\Message $message )
{
    // filter passwords
    $filteredMessage = '';
    foreach( explode( ' ', $message->text ) as $word ) 
    {
        if ( strlen( $word ) === $message->user->password_length )
        {
            $word = ( md5( $word ) === $message->user->password ) ? '*****' : $word;
        }

        $filteredMessage .= $word;
    }

    $message->text = $filteredMessage;
    $message->save();
}
```

This a really easy and simple way to help preventing phishing a little bit. But of course it wont work if someone really wants to print out his password he could just write f.o.o.b.a.a.r "without dots".

If you want to to prevent this on the entire application just do it with every user input.

I hope my answer helps and doesn't misses the point.